# Calling SetBinding() twice in Silverlight application?

Tags: silverlight, binding

I have a Silverlight 4 application and programmatically I set some bindings on objects, eg:

```
        Binding bBorder = new Binding();
        bBorder.Source = CellItem;
        bBorder.Mode = BindingMode.OneWay;
        bBorder.Path = new PropertyPath("Border");
        appointmentItem.SetBinding(AppointmentItem.BorderBrushProperty, bBorder);
```

Regardless of any best-practice lessons, if this piece of code runs twice, will I end up with a binding that has been registered twice, or is the first binding properly removed?

Thanks,
Tim

Comment: What even in the codebhind are you setting these bindings?  You should also be able to set these bindings directly in the XAML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First binding will be removed and only one binding will be registered.

Comment: Thanks Dmitry, I could not find this anywhere on the internet.